# Laravel Dusk $browser->attach() no longer working after machine upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, testing, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I recently moved my dev environment from my old to new MBpro and noticed that all of the tests written with the $browser->attach() method have started failing with the following error message:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException: invalid argument: 'text' is empty
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.2 x86_64)
```

The project is running `Laravel Framework 5.6.39` and I have made sure to update the Chromedrive binaries (using staudenmeir/dusk-updater). I have checked and double-checked that the attach() is being used correctly and have exhausted my ideas of what could be causing the unwanted behavior. All of the other dusk methods are working as designed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but running chrome/chromedriver version 79. Upgrading to version 81 made no difference but when I then ran `composer update` and ensured that I had the correct chromedriver binary (at vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver_linux in my case) the problem disappeared.